# How to run Lightroom on a server, with no physical display -- headless mode?

Tags: software-installation, adobe, headless

I've not found anything in the internet. Is that possible at all?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: @MichalPolovka in a very direct way, мишаня

Comment: Not possible. See [System Requirements](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/system-requirements.html)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ok. Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. The [System Requirements](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/system-requirements.html) clearly state that a 1024x768 display is required so headless is not an option if you intend to actually use the software.